# Facebook Comments Box doesn't scroll within scrollable div

Tags: overflow, parent-child, facebook-comments

I'm working on a website which includes a facebook comment box within a `div` (`div id="article"`) which has an `overflow="auto"` attribute.
The article body scrolls but the comment box extends outside the div in Internet Explorer (I use IE9).
It's working as expected in FF and Chrome.